# Compilation Failing for xalan-c in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, xalan

I am trying to build xalan-c (version 1.12) with icu in Ubuntu but it fails.
Could anyone help me with this.

Environment : Ubuntu 20.04

> Steps to reproduce :
>
> 1. Clone xalan-c
> 2. cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="path to vcpkg installed libraries" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install/Xalan-c -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -Dtranscoder=icu "path to source"
> 3. make

```
Error
[ 95%] Linking C executable SimpleXPathCAPI    
/usr/bin/ld: /home/minhaaj/app/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libicuuc.a(rbbistbl.ao): undefined reference to symbol '_ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3'    
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line    
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status    
make[2]: *** [samples/CMakeFiles/SimpleXPathCAPI.dir/build.make:90: samples/SimpleXPathCAPI] Error 1    
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:842: samples/CMakeFiles/SimpleXPathCAPI.dir/all] Error 2    
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Please note I have applied a patch for configuration error as below in src/xalanc/Utils/MsgCreator/CMakeLists.txt

`target_link_libraries(MsgCreator ICU::uc ICU::i18n)` 
changed to
`target_link_libraries(MsgCreator ICU::uc ICU::i18n ICU::data)`

Comment: ? Why use an alien "libicu" : `undefined reference to symbol '_ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3'` ...... (No errors when using `libicu-dev`)